# Dask String Concat Aggregation

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

Below is a pandas operation. How can I do this in Dask?

```
In [10]: pdf
Out[10]:
  name  text
0    a  asdf
1    b  fdsa
2    a  qwer
3    c  zxcv
4    c  jkl;

In [11]: pdf.groupby('name').aggregate(" ".join)
Out[11]:
           text
name
a     asdf qwer
b          fdsa
c     zxcv jkl;
```

I want to aggregate the `text` column by concatenating the strings in the respective group. Currently Dask only offers aggregations on numeric types. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of *aggregate* you can use *apply*.

Run:

```
pdf.groupby('name').text.apply(lambda grp: ' '.join(grp),
    meta=('text', 'object')).compute()
```

If you want to sort the result by the index, do it on the *Pandas* level
(after *compute()*), adding `.sort_index()` to the above code.

**Another solution** based on custom aggregation:

1. `import itertools as it` (will be used below).
2. Define the following custom aggregation:

   ```
   collect_concat = dd.Aggregation(name='collect_concat',
       chunk=lambda s1: s1.apply(list),
       agg=lambda   s2: s2.apply(lambda chunks: list(it.chain.from_iterable(chunks))),
       finalize=lambda s3: s3.apply(lambda xx: ' '.join(xx))
   )
   ```
3. Compute the result:

   ```
   pdf.groupby('name').text.agg(collect_concat).compute()
   ```

This time the result is ordered by *name*.

## Explanation following a question in a comment as of *2020-06-17*

*dd.Aggregation* is an "envelope" for 3 functions:

- *chunk* - A function to generate a "partial result" for the current
  grouping key, in the current partition.
  In this case a sequence of *text* values is converted into a *list*.
- *agg* - A function to join partial results (for the current grouping
  key), from all partitions. In this case all partial lists are
  concatenated into a single list.
- *finalize* - A function to perform "postprocessing", after *agg*, if any
  is needed.
  Note that the result of *agg* is a **list**, whereas we need a
  **string** - space separated concatenation of this list.
  And this function performs just this task.

For more details and examples check *dask* documentation.

Comment: @valdi-bo custom aggregation is great. Can you give a quick breakdown of what the 3 steps are doing???